# How to create different level combination from multi-dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, combinations, permutation

Here is a single array combination. But I would like to know Whats the best way to combine more than one ?

```
var arr1 = ['a', 'b'];
var arr2 = ['c'];
var arr3 = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
function permutation (list, n) {
    var results = []
    function _perm (list, n, res, start) {
        if (res.length === n) {
            return results.push(res.join(','))
        }
        if (start === list.length) { return }
        _perm(list, n, res.slice(), start + 1)
        res.push(list[start])
        _perm(list, n, res, start + 1)
    }
    _perm(list, n, [], 0)
    return results.length
}
console.log(permutation(arr3, 2))  // print ["e,f", "d,f", "d,e"]
```

**Update question:**

The combination should be permuted in between the arrays but Not include any single array itself. I will also need to combine and permute them into 2D/3D/4D-array respectively.

Thanks for any helps.

Comment: Combine how? Do you mean you want permutations from the union of the lists? Or do you have some specific type of combination in mind?

Comment: `permutation(arr1.concat(arr2, arr3), 2)` ?

Comment: @blex Sorry, did not explain the question well, it should NOT be self-permutation when there are more than one array.

Comment: @Grismar It should be permuted in between the arrays but Not include the single array self-permutation. The only specific condition is I need it to be multi-dimensional arrays. Sorry did not explain it  well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear but I guess you want something like this

```js
const a = ["a", "b"]
const b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const c = ["x", "y", "z"]

const combinateN = arrays => {
    const combN = arrays.reduce((acc, it, i) => {
        if(acc.length === 0){ return it }
        else{ return combinate(it, acc) }
    }, [])
    return combN
}

const combinate = (arr1, arr2 = []) => {
    const comb2 = arr1.map((item1, i) => {
        return arr2.map((item2, j) => {
            return `${item1}, ${item2}`
        })
    })
    return [].concat.apply([], comb2)
}

console.log(combinateN([a, b, c]))
```

This snippet combinates the arrays between them but not between itself, and not duplicating the groups with the same elements in different order. If you explain itself better we will help you better too :P

Comment: Thanks man, what if I want it return as an 2D-array? and when it goes more than five arrays, and how can I combine them and permute into  2D/3D/4D-array respectively?

Comment: Can you explain a bit what did you do in your snippet? I barely understand XD.

Comment: If you pass it some arrays it would return all the combinations of taking one element of each one of the arrays. Per example, if you enter [1,2], ["a", "b"] and ["x", "y"] it would return ["1,a,x", "1,a,y", "1,b,x", 1,b,y", "2,a,x", "2,a,y", "2,b,x", "2,b,y"]

Comment: I mean, instead of change the source arrays, can I change the results to multi-dimensional array?

Comment: I think I have to see examples of the source arrays and the result to understand what do you need, haha